# QQ which one is right?

Tags: sentence, questions

The owner of this equipment has cleared the meeting room, last week.

The meeting room was cleared from the unnecessary equipment by the owner, last week.

Comment: You need give a better description of what the actual circumstances were in order for us to make a choice. As it is, these two sentences give different information about what happened (and neither is particularly clear English).

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: what would you say?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

'Last week' plus present perfect is incorrect it should be the previous week or the week before. The second sentence is correct BUT not very nice because it is in passive voice. In my opinion the first sentence would be better with the appropriate preposition of time.